# Can I use the "dynamic" keyword in a Portable Class Library?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-store-apps, windows-phone-8, portable-class-library

I'm creating a portable class library that is targeting :

1. .NET 4.5
2. Windows Store Apps
3. Windows Phone 7.5+
4. Silverlight 5

Can I safely use the "dynamic" keyword in that library?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Projects targeting Windows Phone 7.5 cannot use "dynamic" - it lacks both the types and runtime support. However, the above combination will work if you change Phone 7.5 to Phone 8